# Error connecting Windows RDP after changing network properties

Tags: windows, ubuntu, rdp

We changed the network gateway at the office so we need to reconfigure all virtual servers to the correct new gateway. Afeter this, we were no longer able to connect to the Windows servers throught RDP from Remmina. The error logged by the process runing from terminal was:

```
[...919] [...] [ERROR][com.freerdp.core] - failed to connect to 192.168.11.104
[...919] [...] [ERROR][com.freerdp.core.nego] - Protocol Security Negotiation Failure
[...919] [...] [ERROR][com.freerdp.core] - freerdp_set_last_error ERRCONNECT_SECURITY_NEGO_CONNECT_FAILED [0x0002000C]
[...919] [...] [ERROR][com.freerdp.core.connection] - Error: protocol security negotiation or connection failure
```

Remmine's GUI does not provide much information about the error.

I have already tried deleting the known_hosts file, connecting with all security protocols and event with the old network configuration. But no way to connect.

Answer (score 0):

Finally the problem was in the new Windows network profile established after changing the gateway. It was automatically set to *Public*, but needed *Private*.
Since I couldn't change it from the operating system GUI, I had to force the change manually from the terminal with the following steps:

Find out the index number of the current connection profile:

```
Get-NetConnectionProfile
```

Set profile as private:

```
Set-NetConnectionProfile -InterfaceIndex <index number> -NetworkCategory Private
```

After changing the profile to *Private* I was able to connect again from Remmina.